# Why can't we read one character at a time from System.in?

Tags: java, stdin

The program below prints each character written on standard in, but only after a new-line has been written (at least on my system!).

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        int c;
        while ((c = System.in.read()) != -1)
            System.out.print((char) c);
    }
}
```

This prevents people from writing stuff like "Press any key to continue" and forces something like "Press enter to continue."

- What is the underlying reason for this?
- Is it a limitation of Java?
- Is this behavior system-dependent (I'm on Ubuntu)? How does it work on Mac? Windows?
- Is it dependent on the specific terminal I run the application in? (For me it behaves like this in Eclipse and in gnome-terminal)
- Is there a workaround?

Comment: see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864076/equivalent-function-to-cs-getch-in-java/10118990#10118990

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What is the underlying reason for this?

Most terminals is line buffered by default, Java does not receive input until a newline.

> Is it a limitation of Java?

Some ancient terminals might only have line-buffered input; though it should be possible to disable buffering in most modern terminal.

> Is this behavior system-dependent (I'm on Ubuntu)? How does it work on Mac? Windows?

Yes.

> Is it dependent on the specific terminal I run the application in? (For me it behaves like this in Eclipse and in gnome-terminal)

Yes.

> Is there a workaround?

There are platform specific hacks. `curse` in Linux and Unix-like platforms, and getch() in Windows. I'm not aware of any cross-platform way.

**related**: Why "Press any key to continue" is bad idea:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

> I'm on Ubuntu
>
> Is there a workaround?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("stty -icanon min 1").waitFor();
```

And after that all reads of System.in in the same process will read 1 character not waiting for EOL.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work unless you use the following: `exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh","-c","stty -icanon min 1 </dev/tty"})`. Then put this in a `finally` block to reset the flag: `exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh","-c","stty icanon </dev/tty"})`

Answer (score 0):

see my answer in [Equivalent function to C's "_getch()" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864076/equivalent-function-to-cs-getch-in-java/10118990#10118990)

```
public static void getCh() {
```

final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    synchronized (frame) {

        frame.setUndecorated(true);

        frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);

        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                synchronized (frame) {

                    frame.setVisible(false);

                    frame.dispose();

                    frame.notify();

                }

            }  



        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {  
        }  

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {  
        }  
    });  
    frame.setVisible(true);  
    try {  
        frame.wait();  
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {  
    }  
}

}