# when are characters stored in the Buffer

Tags: runtime, buffer

I just want to know when are characters that sb enter from the keyboard stored in the buffer? I mean : when the character key is pressed, or when enter is pressed, or there is another timing? my question is especially for c++ Console apps, but it will be even better if the answers contained every case, or a general case!

thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on the specific console in question.

Even though they are for different languages, same rules apply to as how the terminal/environment feeds your program with data on standard input:

- [How to read a single char from the console in Java (as the user types it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it)
- [Why can't we read one character at a time from System.in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007534/why-cant-we-read-one-character-at-a-time-from-system-in)

---

[This thread](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/246126-read-single-character-without-press-enter-just-like-getc-c-language) supposedly has a working example for Visual Studio.

Comment: if I have to specify, I mean Visual c++ 6.0 and Microsoft Visual c++ 2008

Comment: As I wrote, same rules apply to all console applications.