# Reading a string in Character array without using any String function, not even charAt in Java

Tags: java, c++, arrays, string

I want to read a String in a char array without using any of String class function, not even charAt(), lenght() in Java. I know one method char c=(char) System.in.read(). But in this, the user char write a whole sentence on command Line even for inputting a single char. I want that user will be able to type one character and then i can do some operations on it, then the next character on the same line....(as we do in c++) . Please give me some suggetstions. I want a code working similar like in c++

```
// c++ code
char c, d[50];
cin.get(c); 
int i=0;
while(c != '\n')
{
    d[i++]=c;
    ...           //any expressions
    ...
    cin.get(c); 
}
```

Comment: First hint to avoid annoying Java programmers: it's Java, not JAVA.

Comment: Your C++ code is flawed. `i` is not initialised.

Comment: And why do you want it to be done, as java simplifies it with String methods

Comment: It sounds like what you're *really* asking for is: "Can I read a character from the console without waiting for a line break" - which has very little to do with "reading a string in character array without using any string function"

Comment: Are you also asking that the user inputs a `char` and perform some operation WHILE waiting for another char? I.E multithreading?

Comment: yes i want to read a character from console without waiting for a line break.

Comment: i also wanted to know methods of reading a string in character array without using any string function.
I was asked to perform in an Interview, where i have to reverse  all words in a sentence without using string class and any string function and also the number of words in a string should be odd.

Comment: Well regarding the reversing, would something like that do?            `System.out.println(new StringBuilder("abc").reverse());`

Comment: thanx, but they told me not to use any inbuilt functions similar to String class. I have to work at character levels only and i had to create my own functions, thats why i am asking.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to handle one character at a time.

See on SO [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007534/why-cant-we-read-one-character-at-a-time-from-system-in) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it). You may work around this problem with some headaches and on particular OSes *and* no data from `System.in` but rather from your own structures. If you find a way to flush `System.in` at each keystroke, your problem is solved. As far as I know, you can't register a keyboard IRQ from Java.

Your no-`String` requirement is the easy part, as you may use the same structure as you would in C++. The problem is the mechanism behind `cin.get()` which has no analogue in Java.