# Java Concatenation of Strings Through CMD input

Tags: java, string, input, concatenation

So I have two classes:

```
class ConcatTesting{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException{
        char inLetter;
        String input="";

        //This loops takes line of cmd and makes the input variable into that string
        for(;;){
            inLetter=(char) System.in.read(); //get next char

            //if the line hasn't ended then add that char to input
            if(inLetter!='\n'){
                input+=String.valueOf(inLetter);
            }else{
                //other wise line has ended so input is finished
                break;
            }
        }

        //removes extra white-spaces
        input.trim();

        //test what input is to make sure it is working correctly
        System.out.println(input);

        //test concat function
        UseConcat.ask(input);

        UseConcat.ask("pie");
    }
}

class UseConcat{
    public static void ask(String str){
        System.out.println("What does " + str +" mean?");
    }
}
```

In the program I call the static method `UseConcat.ask(String str)` twice.

When the argument in the `UseConcat.ask(String str)` is the `input` variable, the concatenation seems to fail. However, when I call `UseConcat.ask(String str)` with the argument being a random string, the concatenation works.

The `input` variable is the first written line of the cmd converted to a string.

Here is an example image.

[image: Example Image]

As shown in the image, the input variable is set to WOA.

However `UseConcat.ask(input);` prints out **mean?oes WOA** intsead of **What does WOA mean?**

When input is printed: `System.out.println(input);` it prints **WOA** as normal.

On the other hand when I call `UseConcat.ask("pie");` It works and prints: **What does pie mean?**

Comment: Why not use a `Scanner` to capture user input?

Comment: @RyanJ Seems to work with scanner but why is it failing with how I currently do it?

Comment: I can tell you it has to do with the behavior of the terminal, and not the specific code. It works using an IDE with terminal emulation. I suspect you're being bit by something like what [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007534/why-cant-we-read-one-character-at-a-time-from-system-in) describes. I'd suggest switching to `Scanner` though, since it's a little more robust and more in-line with current practice.

Answer (score 0):

Text lines on Windows (usually for files but always for console window) end with *two* characters CR (Carriage Return) and LF (Linefeed), which are (most easily) written `\r` and `\n` in Java. You remove only the LF and then output "What does WOA{CR} mean?" and the {CR} character moves the cursor to the left margin and causes the " mean?" part to overwrite the "What d" part. Your `input.trim()` would have fixed this if you hadn't discarded the result. Other platforms are different; Unix uses only LF, and AIUI MacOSX uses only CR.

The Java methods designed to deal with text like `Scanner` or more basically `BufferedReader.readLine()` handle any combination of CR and LF for you, with much less code in your application, and more efficiently; repeatedly doing String += letter is horrendously inefficient for long input -- although if you run this program only in a console window that will limit the input line to some not absurdly huge amount.