# Why doesn't BufferedReader buffer the input?

Tags: java, io

I ran the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int character;
        do{
            character = reader.read();
            System.out.println(character);
        } while(character != '\n');
    }
```

and was actually confused by the behaviour. I thought the default buffer size of the BufferedReader is large enough to hold more than 1 character.

But, when I entered

```
a__NEW_LINE__
```

it causes the character to be printed along with new line. Why? I expected that the buffer is not full, therefore there should be no output.

Comment: Duplicate question. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007534/why-cant-we-read-one-character-at-a-time-from-system-in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BufferedReader` buffers data when possible. In this case there is no data to buffer. So, it returns what you enter immediately. `BufferedReader` is useful when is used with large streams such as a file (`FileInputStream`) and in all cases the read method returns one character while behind the scene, `BufferedReader` reads more data (depends on buffer size) from related `InputStream` and caches it to improve performance.