# Trying to use scnr.next to read a user input for a char

Tags: java

Heres my code:
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class BasicInput {
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  int userInt = 0;
  double userDouble = 0.0;
  char userLetter = 'z';      

  userInt = scnr.nextInt();
  userDouble = scnr.nextDouble();
  userLetter = scnr.nextLine();

  System.out.println("Enter integer: " + userInt);
  System.out.println("Enter double: " + userDouble);
  System.out.println("Enter letter: " + userLetter);
```

When I run it with the letter input "z", it gives me this error

```
    BasicInput.java:13: error: incompatible types
userLetter = scnr.nextLine();
                            ^
```

required: char

found:    String

1 error

What do I do so that it will read a letter as input and output it?

Comment: What has this got to do with javaScript?

Answer (score 1):

This is trying to store the value of a String into a char - it will not fit

Try

```
String userLetter = scnr.nextLine();
```

then just use the first char

```
userletter.charAt (0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`nextLine()` accepts `String` You need to consider `userLetter = scnr.next().charAt(0);` Take a look at [Why can't we read one character at a time from System.in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007534/why-cant-we-read-one-character-at-a-time-from-system-in) for further detials about why it's happening.