# Why is this do-while loop not stopping?

Tags: java, loops

The purpose of this loop is to stop as soon as a period key is typed, but it is  not working and I did not understand why.

```
import java.io.IOException;


public class ControlFlowTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    char ch ;

    do{
        ch = (char) System.in.read();
    }while(ch != '.');

}
```

Comment: tried checking what `ch`  cotains?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: [Works for me.](http://ideone.com/bu5wlT)

Comment: I think the OP's problem is that the `read()` call is blocking until an EOL is given, which is not what they're expecting to happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't we read one character at a time from System.in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007534/why-cant-we-read-one-character-at-a-time-from-system-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use Scanner as System.in.read() will block until a carriage return is entered.  Try this:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class ControlFlowTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        char ch ;

        Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            ch = scanner.next().charAt(0);
        } while(ch != '.');
    }
}
```

Comment: This will do the same thing, only worse. With your solution entering "abc." and pressing enter will not exit the loop.