# Read any key to continue Java

Tags: java, key

How can I implement the press ANY key to continue in Java. In C I use getch() and it works fine but Java I must press enter in every read method implement in every OutputStream class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Already mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it

Comment: is this console or desktop application?

Comment: I saw this question but I want to know how to do it without JNI? It's a console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way which I found was whith JNI and C.

Answer (score 0):

I found a code, Equivalent function to C's “_getch()

I have given answer for this question [Equivalent function to C's "_getch()" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864076/equivalent-function-to-cs-getch-in-java/10118990#10118990) see my answer here

or use the code

public static void getCh() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        synchronized (frame) {
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
            frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    synchronized (frame) {
                        frame.setVisible(false);
                        frame.dispose();
                        frame.notify();
                    }
                }

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {  
            }  

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {  
            }  
        });  
        frame.setVisible(true);  
        try {  
            frame.wait();  
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {  
        }  
    }  
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code if you're using windows.

```java
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "pause").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
```

and import following package.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
```

and change main function to this.

```java
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException
```