# Input in Java without pressing enter

Tags: java

I want to take any input in Java without pressing the enter key. Actually I want to make a password input program, so that as soon as the user enter any character, I can clear the screen and replace the characters with an equal number of asterisks ("*"), like the typical password entries made anywhere in the web. Most importantly, I would like to do the same in the Java Terminal Window, not by using those applet methods. Please tell me if i would have to supply more details. I am using BlueJ.

Thank you,
Mayank.

Comment: Not possible without going native. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864076/equivalent-function-to-cs-getch-in-java as well.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have a look at the [`Console`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html)'s `readPassword(...)` methods (needs Java 6+).

Or, when using Java 5 (or less), have a look at this article: [Password Masking in the Java Programming Language](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/pwordmask/), especially the paragraph ***Command-Line Input Masking***.