# Exit java program using ctrl+z?

Tags: java, keylistener, key-bindings

I am creating a very simple program, asking the user to guess words. Guessing words works just with `Scanner` and `System.out.println()`, so its very simple and no user interface is needed.

The guessing of words is done with eclipse. Now I need to add a function, which will allow the user to exit the "program" anytime by clicking <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and when they do that I'll need also to print out possible words they could've have guessed.

But I do not know how to add the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> exit function. Can anyone suggest anything on how to ? The word guessing is a loop.

Comment: `The guessing of words is done with eclipse.` and `no user interface is needed` I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're answer is simple:

**You can't do that!**

Because you're using a command-line window. In command-line there is no listeners  like `KeyListener` or `MouseListener....`.

If you want to do so, leave the command-line and go learn `Swing` in java.

See this question: [How to get input without pressing enter every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555515/how-to-get-input-without-pressing-enter-every-time/17555974#17555974)