# how do i stop a infinite loop using char(input from keyboard method-System.in.read( ). System.in?

Tags: java, loops, input

```
class Copied{
    public static void main(String args[])     throws java.io.IOException {  
        int i;  
        System.out.println("Press S to stop.");  
        for(i = 0; (char) System.in.read() != 'S'; i++)    
            System.out.println("Pass #" + i);
    } 
}
```

i couldn't get expected result.

Comment: Works fine for me. What is your expected result? Or are you confused about the double "Pass #" output per entered char?

Comment: What is the expected result? I would expect that the above loop stops upon entering S.

Comment: i wanted a infinite loop that stop after pressing S so that i don;t have to push enter after certain  output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555515/how-to-get-input-without-pressing-enter-every-time

Answer (score 0):

What the above code does tricky is

```
(char) System.in.read() != 'S'
```

the `.read()` would

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is
>    returned as an `int` in the range `0` to `255`

So, your input are treated as :

```
Input : a
Output  : Pass #0 // for a
Pass #1 //for Enter


Input : all
Output : Pass #2 // a
Pass #3 //l
Pass #4 //l
Pass #5 // Enter
```

and similarly for any string unless it includes a character `S`

```
Input : stingWithSHere
Output : Pass #6 //s
Pass #7 //t
Pass #8 //i
Pass #9 //n
Pass #10 //g
Pass #11 //W
Pass #12 //i
Pass #13 //t
Pass #14 //h
```

and then it terminates. Hope that makes things look clear.

---

To *strictly* restrict the input from the user you can instead use -

```
new Scanner(System.in).next(".").charAt(0) != 'S'
```

---

With the updated question, the link shared by @Tom answers it for now -

[How to get input without pressing enter every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555515/how-to-get-input-without-pressing-enter-every-time)

Comment: Actually i wanted the loop to go on unless i enter 'S' such that i don't have to push enter after certain display i want it to be continue can we do that but this one is also helpful for me thank you.