# What to write so that when "enter" is pressed, then code proceeds further?

Tags: java

Please help me in the below code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class A
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter first number : ");
        a = Sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter second number : ");
        b = Sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Sum is : " + (a + b));
        System.out.print("Press enter to continue...");
        /* HERE IS MY DOUBT */
        /* WHAT TO WRITE HERE SO THAT WHEN "ENTER" IS PRESSED THEN CODE PROCEEDS */
    }
}
```

Like in C language we can use getch() to hold a program. Is there something similar in Java too?

I have already tried Sc.nextLine(). The problem with Sc.nextLine() is that, in it first I have to enter a value and then press enter and then the code proceeds.
But what I want is to just press enter and proceed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent function to C's "\_getch()" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864076/equivalent-function-to-cs-getch-in-java)

Comment: "......THEN CODE PROCEEDS" - then code is proceeds to where? what you want to do further? By default you program will be stopped after executing the last line. You need not to exit it manually if you don't have a *infinite loop* that needs to be closed when certain condition matches.

Comment: How about `sc.nextLine()`?

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon Ya in this question the code is exiting but there may be cases where just to increase interaction with the user I would require something just like this.

Comment: @JimGarrison I tried it, but it does not proceed until i enter a value and then press enter

Comment: please explain your thought what you want to do. May be what you are trying to do can be handled by a method recursion that executes each time after completion of a task and then again ask for user inputs.

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon What I'm trying to do is suppose, I created a object, and for this I'm showing message "Object Was Created Successfully!". But here just after the message I want to "hold" my program until user presses enter.

Comment: Then what you really want your last console output to be is: **Press Enter to continue...** correct? `Sc.nextLine(); while(!Sc.nextLine().equals("")) { }` and then: `System.out.println("Code Continuing...");`.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Yes, I want my code in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for a single key stroke event

```
public class EnterKeyEvent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Press a key");
        String entry = sc.nextLine();
        if(!"".equals(entry)) {
            System.out.println("Enter key not pressed");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Enter key pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

Like if you press `Enter key` then `else` block will be executed, but if `Enter key` is pressed after pressing some other key [like **asdf** and then Enter key] `if` block will be executed.

When I tried this code I was expecting the value of `entry` to come as `\n` but it was getting an `empty String` value. And that's what I did in the code.

Comment: Can you explain the logic also please

Answer (score 0):

Do the following,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    //your code...

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("press enter to exit...");
        String keyPressed = sc.nextLine();
        sc.nextLine();

        if (keyPressed.isEmpty()) break;
    }
}
```

Hope this your work!

Answer (score 0):

Robot or Actions Class
Press the desired Key by making the object of actions or Robot class.
Like
Actions act=New Action(webdriver Dr)
Act.PressyourKey
Use the auto suggestions.This is how we press any desired Key you can use this Act.pressyourKey if true in a loop and it should execute your code

Comment: what are you trying to say??

Comment: Oh.. You made me worry there ... Haha

Answer (score 0):

Try using code in this class but this works only form command line . you can't use it in IDE's console .`c.reader` will return null if you use in IDE

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
public class GetChar {

public static void main(String  args[]) {

    int num=0;
    Console c =System.console();
    Reader r = c.reader();
try {
    num=    r.read();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(num);

}

}
```

The value of num will be 10 if '\n' is pressed pressed i,e Enter . I hope your code can use this logic

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class A
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        while(true) {
            Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter first number : ");
            int a = Sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter second number : ");
            int b = Sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Sum is : " + (a + b));
            System.out.println("Press enter to continue...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see the solution to my problem in this code.?