# how do I get the character and process it in this getch class from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864076/equivalent-function-to-cs-getch-in-java

Tags: java, c++

Here is the code C++ i use and then that is provided in the link, and I am eager to implement it but do not see where it returns a character in my current program I use:

```
x = _getch(); //take input without waiting for an enter key pressed

// upon input interrupt thread 
interrupted.store(true);
```

I use the user input it to interrupt my thread in C++, and so I assign x the char value for input processing .. I am looking for the same functionality..

how do I do that with this java code from the link:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

class getch
{
    public static void getCh()
    {  
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();  
        synchronized(frame)
        {  
            frame.setUndecorated(true);  
            frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);  
            frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
            {  
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
                {  
                    synchronized(frame)
                    {  
                        frame.setVisible(false);  
                        frame.dispose();  
                        frame.notify();  
                    }  
                }  

                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
                {  
                }  

                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
                {  
                }  
            });
            frame.setVisible(true);  
            try
            {  
                frame.wait();  
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e1)
            {  
            }  
        }  
    }
}
```

It seems there is no return and I am having trouble seeing where the code is "grabbing and storing" the character.  Also how am I calling this in my main in java as I am converting this program?

Comment: am I asking the wrong question here ... it seems if it is supposed to do a getCH function then it should return a character