# am I spawning threads and causing a memory leak?

Tags: java, c++, multithreading

I am converting a C++ program to Java for same implementation as a learning exercise and this java has a lot of things I am not yet familiar with, I had a long break in my work in the field.

Well here is the code:

```
public class MythicQuestDriver {
    
    public static void clrscr(){

        //Clears Screen in java

        try {

            if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows"))

                new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();

            else

                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {}

    }
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int x = 0;  
        
    MythicClock ElflordsTimepiece = new MythicClock(7,7,7);
    
    ElflordsTimepiece.printMythicClockDetails();
    
    do {
    new MainGameThread();
    clrscr();
    

    }while(x != '5');
}}
```

the clear screen function is from https://intellipaat.com/community/294/java-clear-the-console

and here is the thread class I slightly modified:

```
package MythicQuestGame;

import java.lang.*;

public class MainGameThread implements Runnable{
    
    Thread t;

    MainGameThread() {

          t = new Thread(this);
          System.out.println("Executing " + t.getName());
       
          // this will call run() fucntion
          t.start();
            
          /* interrupt the threads
          if (!t.interrupted()) {
             t.interrupt();
          }*/
          
          // block until other threads finish
          try {  
             t.join();
          } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
       }
    
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("thread ran");
        
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}
```

and when I run I get a second like tiker but it goes thread1 thread2 thread3 ... I know I am running an infinte loop and that is by design as I am working towards an interupt like getch in c++ from: [Last Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626360/how-do-i-get-the-character-and-process-it-in-this-getch-class-from-https-stack.)

So I have not got to the interupt thread join stuff yet, but am trying to follow the intent of what happens in my C++ code. I am interested to know if I need a destructor method or does the way threads work does it get its memory footprint removed after it runs because if I run a thread a second or 3 times a second or more it is gonna generate so many threads, but it would not matter if they are all destroyed after they run?

in my c++ program the implementation runs like this:

```
int main() {
    std::atomic<bool> interrupted;
    char x;

  do {
        interrupted.store(false);

        // create a new thread that does stuff in the background

        std::thread timerThread([&]()
            {

                while (!interrupted)
                {

            // does game stuff moves monsters 
            // checks for random encounters every aprox 15 sec
            // runs a clearscreen every 15 seconds and refresh output
            // hosts enemy attacks if in encounter
            // updates clock timer one sec every 3  passes
            // runs every .3 seconds

            }});
            x = _getch();
        //take input without waiting for an enterkey pressed
       // upon input interrupt thread 


        interrupted.store(true);
        timerThread.join();

    // here the program does things like:
    //based on input does character actions like move or attack
    // takes almost second sleep and adds one second to clock timer
    // runs a clear screen and new output

    

    } while (x != '5'); // exit condition
}
```

Comment: why do you bother using threads for this?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you're trying to achieve a temporized screen clearing, right?

In Java there's no such thing as **destructors**, specially when talking about threads where scheduling and thread's memory is mainly handled by the JVM itself (unless you're using shared objects like **monitors**), so I think the problem in your code is **how** you're spawning threads. You should try to do that this way:

`MainGameThread constructor`

```
MainGameThread(){
    System.out.println("Executing " + t.getName());
}
```

`MythicQuestDriver.java`

```
...
// Creates the Runnable just once
MainGameThread runnable = new MainGameThread();
do {
    // Use the same Runnable for each thread you want to spawn
    Thread t = new Thread(runnable);

    // Start the thread and immediately stop and wait for its conclusion
    t.start();
    t.join();

    // Clear the screen
    clrscr();
} while (x != 5)
```

With that said, **I do not think you should spawn threads in a loop** at all, unless you know exactly how many threads will spawn.

Moreover, by starting a thread and then immediately stopping in order to wait for its conclusion you're really doing something that makes threads useless: in other words, you should reconsider your game's logic and adapt it to the way Java works, and not viceversa. For a simple example like the one you asked, a thread is not even necessary, you should place your game's logic inside the main loop and clear the screen once its execution ends, eventually using threads for complementary jobs!

Comment: luco5826 it sounds like you are saying I should just use loops and not threads at all .. I am a bit vexed I love the idea of useing the threads but you say they should be used for complementary jobs, can you describe that a bit further.. I can kind of see your point if I am not using the thread correctly at all.. perhaps you can go into that a bit more for me.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I have updated the question with the code to show the C++ base functionality with the thread I am trying to duplicate

Comment: @ElflordBane The issue is that your Java code is structured differently than the C++ code. It's hard to tell where your misunderstandings are if your translate the C++ code like that. You should probably start by translating the code to the *exact* Java equivalent to not get confused about other things in the meantime. The given C++ code can be translated 1 to 1 to Java: Java has `AtomicBoolean`, lambda expressions, do-while loops, `Thread#join` and `Scanner` to read from the console.

Comment: @ElflordBane I totally agree with you, I understand that thread optimization is a fantastic thing to implement. Now that you uploaded an example it's clearer that what you need is a monitor, which is a single instance object shared across multiple threads. Every operation that alter the game state is done through that monitor, so that you can spawn how many threads you want for the calculations and then use the monitor just to update the game's state. You should totally look a bit further into that

Comment: Thank you very much for all the feed back